# Floating Social Media Overlaps on Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

```
<div class="bookmark" style='top: 35%; position: fixed; left: 6%;'>
<div id='pageshare' title="Get this from amazingeworld.com">
<div class='shareaholic-canvas' data-app='share_buttons' data-app-id='10714211'></div>
</div></div>
```

Here is the image:

[image: here's the image]

The Floating Social Media are overlapping in footer section. please check the image above

Answer (score 1):

You should change :

```
<div class="bookmark" style='top: 35%; position: fixed; left: 6%;'>
```

to

```
<div class="bookmark" style='bottom: 20px; position: fixed; left: 6%;'>
```

You can remplace "20px" by the height of your footer.

Tip : if you have access to the *CSS* file, you should avoid using inline CSS and put the style where it should be : in an external stylesheet.

Comment: its getting worse  :( s there a code to change to make the floating social media box like this blog smashingtips.com/wildlife-photograph-tips its floating inside the article and not overlapping, the like button follows everything I scroll til the end of the article.

Comment: @user2836892 What do you mean getting worse? can you describe the issue please?

Comment: Like the Floating widgets in this website smashingtips.com/wildlife-photograph-tips it won't overlap

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution, you could set `style='top: 35%;` to something lower, but beware that this will not necessarily look nice on all screen sizes.

You may have to come up with a different solution for those special cases, eg. use [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Is there a code to change to make the floating social media box like this blog http://smashingtips.com/wildlife-photograph-tips its floating inside the article and not overlapping, the like button follows everything I scroll til the end of the article.

Comment: sure there is... have a look through the net and if you find something, try it out, then if you're stuck with it for some reason, you can come back and ask another question... in the interim, you may vote one (or more) of these answers up or accept one as the correct one if it solved your issue... (big gray check mark)